# Unix - if else EOF error

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement

I am writing the following code:

```
if [ $opt -ge $max -o $opt -le  0 ]
then
    echo "Bad";
else
    echo "Good";
    if [ $opt = "\" -o $opt = "/"  ]
    then
        echo "Good";
    else
        echo "Invlaid"; //Line number 21
    fi
fi //Line number 23 no Line number 24.
```

this shows an error:

```
./file.sh: line 21: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./file.sh: line 24: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

If I place this code:

```
if [ $opt -ge $max -o $opt -le  0 ]
then
    echo "Bad";
else
    echo "Good";
fi //Line number 23 no Line number 24.
```

Then there is **no error**. I am not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: See the syntax highlighting - you have accidentily "escaped" the second quote in `if [ $opt = "\" -o $opt = "/"  ]`.

Comment: Note that `-o` for logical OR is deprecated; you should use `[ "$opt" -ge "$max" ] || [ "$opt" -le 0 ]` instead--and quote your expansions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash `\` inside double quotes needs to be escaped or else **you can use single quotes** like this:

```
if [ $opt = '\' -o $opt = '/' ]; then
   echo "Good"
fi
```

Single quotes treat the wrapped string literally that's the precise reason single quote in shell cannot be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

Where you write "\" you start a string literal whose first character is a double quote. To include a back slash in a string you have to precede it with another:

```
"\\"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
opt="\\"

echo $opt
\

if [ $opt = "/" -o $opt = "\\" ]; then echo "Hi"; else echo "bye"; fi
Hi
```